# error while install rpm package：libssl.so.10 and libcrypto.so.10

Tags: linux, rpm, yum, centos8

I tried installing **mysql-community-libs** through **yum** with the following error：

```sh
[root@liaghost ~]# rpm -ivh mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64.rpm 
warning: mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 5072e1f5: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) is needed by mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64
    libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) is needed by mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64
    libssl.so.10()(64bit) is needed by mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64
    libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) is needed by mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64
```

Then I checked and found that **openssl** was already installed：

```sh
[root@liaghost yum.repos.d]# ls /usr/lib64/ | grep -e ssl.so -e crypto.so
libcrypto.so
libcrypto.so.1.1
libcrypto.so.1.1.1c
libk5crypto.so
libk5crypto.so.3
libk5crypto.so.3.1
libssl.so
libssl.so.1.1
libssl.so.1.1.1c
[root@liaghost yum.repos.d]# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1c FIPS  28 May 2019
```

Is this because I installed the wrong version of **openssl**?

Answer (score 4):

suggest you to install compatibility package to older version of openssl

```
dnf install compat-openssl10
```